# Parking via SMS in Sofia, Bulgaria

Tags: cellphones, automobiles, bulgaria, sofia

In Sofia, Bulgaria there are two parking zones - blue and green, and for both of them is possible to pay via SMS. My problem is that I have no longer a Bulgarian SIM-card, and I wonder if it's possible to pay with a foreign SIM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. The Center for City Mobility (Център за градска мобилност) in Sofia which is responsible for the rapid transit system in the city [has this to say on SMS parking](http://www.sofiatraffic.bg/en/parking/parkirane-chrez-sms/p/1) (emphasis mine):

> Customers of **Bulgaria’s mobile operators** may park on public streets and squares in the municipality, which are within the limits of the Blue Zone Scheme for paid short-stay parking...

This doesn't mention specifically that non-Bulgarian operators are excluded, but from experience with similar systems in other countries, this won't be possible. I assume this is done to simplify collection of what is due without having to deal with every single mobile operator in the world.

You might also be interested in the [SMS Parking](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=bg.sportal.smsparking&hl=en) application for Android, though you still need to have a SIM card from a Bulgarian mobile operator.